# Checking which checkbox in Javascript is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

On a page that I'm creating I have 20 Rad Buttons and their toggle type is CheckBox
(button that inside of it there is a checkbox).
In java script I want to know which "CheckBox" is checked in order to disable the rest of the buttons is there any simple way to do so?????
(let's say that Checkbox 1 is checked so all the 19 other checkboxs should be disabled 
I have 20 button I don't want that my code will be a spaghetti code.

Here is my Code:

**asp.net**

```
 <telerik:RadButton ID="btnPic1" runat="server" ToggleType="CheckBox" ButtonType="StandardButton"  AutoPostBack="False" CommandName="GetPicture1Info" OnClientClicked="DisablePicture">
                          <ToggleStates>
                           <telerik:RadButtonToggleState Text="Select Picture 1" PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleCheckboxChecked" CssClass="rbSkinnedButtonChecked" />
                           <telerik:RadButtonToggleState Text="Select Picture 1" PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleCheckbox"  />
                          </ToggleStates>
                     </telerik:RadButton>

 <telerik:RadButton ID="btnPic2" runat="server" ToggleType="CheckBox" ButtonType="StandardButton" AutoPostBack="False" CommandName="GetPicture2Info" OnClientClicked="DisablePicture">
                          <ToggleStates>
                           <telerik:RadButtonToggleState Text="Select Picture 2" PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleCheckboxChecked" CssClass="rbSkinnedButtonChecked" />
                           <telerik:RadButtonToggleState Text="Select Picture 2" PrimaryIconCssClass="rbToggleCheckbox" />
                          </ToggleStates>
                     </telerik:RadButton>
```

**JS**

```
function DisablePicture(sender, args) {
            var Pic1 = $find("<%=btnPic1.ClientID %>");
            var Pic2 = $find("<%=btnPic2.ClientID %>");
            var Pic3 = $find("<%=btnPic3.ClientID %>");
            var Pic4 = $find("<%=btnPic4.ClientID %>");
            var Pic5 = $find("<%=btnPic5.ClientID %>");
            var Pic6 = $find("<%=btnPic6.ClientID %>");
            var Pic7 = $find("<%=btnPic7.ClientID %>");
            var Pic8 = $find("<%=btnPic8.ClientID %>");
            var Pic9 = $find("<%=btnPic9.ClientID %>");
            var Pic10 = $find("<%=btnPic10.ClientID %>");
            var Pic11 = $find("<%=btnPic11.ClientID %>");
            var Pic12 = $find("<%=btnPic12.ClientID %>");
            var Pic13 = $find("<%=btnPic13.ClientID %>");
            var Pic14 = $find("<%=btnPic14.ClientID %>");
            var Pic15 = $find("<%=btnPic15.ClientID %>");
            var Pic16 = $find("<%=btnPic16.ClientID %>");
            var Pic17 = $find("<%=btnPic17.ClientID %>");
            var Pic18 = $find("<%=btnPic18.ClientID %>");
            var Pic19 = $find("<%=btnPic19.ClientID %>");
            var Pic20 = $find("<%=btnPic20.ClientID %>");
            if (Pic1.get_checked() == true) {
                Pic2.set_enabled(false);
                Pic3.set_enabled(false);
                Pic4.set_enabled(false);
                Pic5.set_enabled(false);
                Pic6.set_enabled(false);
                Pic7.set_enabled(false);
                Pic8.set_enabled(false);
                Pic9.set_enabled(false);
                Pic10.set_enabled(false);
                Pic11.set_enabled(false);
                Pic12.set_enabled(false);
                Pic13.set_enabled(false);
                Pic14.set_enabled(false);
                Pic15.set_enabled(false);
                Pic16.set_enabled(false);
                Pic17.set_enabled(false);
                Pic18.set_enabled(false);
                Pic19.set_enabled(false);
                Pic20.set_enabled(false);
                __doPostBack("<%=btnGetPictureInformation.UniqueID %>", "");
            } else if (Pic2.get_checked() == true) {
                Pic2.set_enabled(true);
                Pic1.set_enabled(false);
                Pic3.set_enabled(false);
                Pic4.set_enabled(false);
                Pic5.set_enabled(false);
                Pic6.set_enabled(false);
                Pic7.set_enabled(false);
                Pic8.set_enabled(false);
                Pic9.set_enabled(false);
                Pic10.set_enabled(false);
                Pic11.set_enabled(false);
                Pic12.set_enabled(false);
                Pic13.set_enabled(false);
                Pic14.set_enabled(false);
                Pic15.set_enabled(false);
                Pic16.set_enabled(false);
                Pic17.set_enabled(false);
                Pic18.set_enabled(false);
                Pic19.set_enabled(false);
                Pic20.set_enabled(false);
                __doPostBack("<%=btnGetPictureInformation.UniqueID %>", "");
}
}
```

Comment: LEARN ARRAY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What's the generated HTML for a button and checkboxes?

Comment: Thanks for your lovely replay! newboyhun

Comment: @user3654570 Most of us aren't ASP.Net developers and it will greatly help to see what HTML source it generates out of the ASP.Net controls to answer your question.

Comment: What do you mean HTML source? It's a long code.

Comment: You're looking for input type=radio when you only want one option selected out of many.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I can suggest arrays as one way to solve this. If you can use radio buttons instead of checkboxes, the entire problem may go away, but for the sake of the argument:

```
var controls = [];
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic1.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic2.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic3.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic4.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic5.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic6.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic7.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic8.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic9.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic10.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic11.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic12.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic13.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic14.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic15.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic16.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic17.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic18.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic19.ClientID %>"));
controls.push($find("<%=btnPic20.ClientID %>"));
```

This is a rather tedious way of adding all of the references to your controls to an array, so that you can loop through them like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
  if (controls[i].get_checked() != true)
    controls[i].set_enabled(false);
}
```

This should accomplish what you are trying to do, if I understood your question correctly.